# Avoid type casting when selecting a row

Tags: python, pandas, typing

I've got a DataFrame with enforced data types, which are quite important to my application:

```py
df = (pd.DataFrame([(1, 1, 1000), 
                    (1, 2, 2000)], 
                   columns=['id', 'fk', 'value'])
      .astype({'id': pd.Int32Dtype(), 
               'fk': pd.Int32Dtype(), 
               'value': pd.Float32Dtype()})

df.dtypes.to_dict()
```

correctly yields:

```py
{'id': Int32Dtype(), 'fk': Int32Dtype(), 'value': Float32Dtype()}
```

However, when I pick one row using `.iloc`, Pandas suddently casts everything into float -- presumably because it turns it into a Series which wants a data type:

```py
df.iloc[0].dtypes
```

yields:

```py
Float64Dtype()
```

That causes downstream problems, as I need the data in the correct types. How can I pull out a single row while maintaining the correct types?

Comment: You can use `df.iloc[0:0+1]` to get a `dataframe` with one row.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Prefer `df.iloc[[0]]`?

Comment: @Corralien - Yes. Your approach is easier to read and less computation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to extract a `Series` (one row) from a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df
   id  fk   value
0   1   1  1000.0  # Int32, Int32, Float32
1   1   2  2000.0

>>> df.iloc[0]
id          1.0
fk          1.0
value    1000.0
Name: 0, dtype: Float64
```

So you have 2 rows of `Int32` and 1 row of `Float32`. However, it's not possible to mix dtypes for a `Series` (or a column of `DataFrame`). Pandas have to cast your `Series` into a common dtype that fits your values. Here, `Float64`.

Now a different case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 1, 1000), (1, 2, 2000)], columns=['id', 'fk', 'value']) \
     .astype({'id': pd.Int8Dtype(), 'fk': pd.Int16Dtype(), 'value': pd.Int32Dtype()})
```

```
>>> df.dtypes
id        Int8
fk       Int16
value    Int32
dtype: object

>>> df.iloc[0]
id          1
fk          1
value    1000
Name: 0, dtype: Int32
```

In this case, Pandas finds a common dtype (a superset) to enclose values.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments by @MichaelSzczesny and @Corralien (thank you!), I understand it's not possible to have a Series with multiple types, but a DataFrame with one row (e.g. `df.iloc[[0]]`) keeps the data types.

I've now used that to extract the data into a `dict` instead, keeping the base data types (`int`, `float` etc.), which is good enough for my use case:

```py
df.iloc[[0]].to_dict('records')[0]
```

yields:

```py
{'id': 1, 'fk': 1, 'value': 1000.0}
```